# Logging microservice - error level in URI or body?

Tags: rest, api-design

For my use case I need to create a microservice that receives log messages through HTTP.

I'm wondering about the reasons to pick either of these:

```
Method: POST
URI: /{logLevel}/
Body: {
 "message": "..."
}
```

```
Method: POST
URI: /
Body: {
 "level": {either string or enum},
 "message": "..."
}
```

I feel like with the first method I can map each log level to an entirely different flow with ease and avoid validating the values by myself (the library does this using the predefined URIs).
But are there reasons to prefer the second method? What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a right or wrong way of doing this. It really depends on which approach makes sense for you given your context.

With that being said though :), I would go for solution 2 and send the log level inside the body. The reason is that you are dealing with one type of resource here, a `LogMessage` with two properties, the log level and the text message. It's more intuitive to send one type of resource to one base endpoint. In solution 1, you are sending one resource to many endpoints.

Another intuitive thing would be that, at some later moment, I'm expecting to see these log messages and inspect them to draw some conclusions about the process they are logging. Will you again think of creating different endpoints to retrieve different error levels? Or will you have only one endpoint that retrieves all types of log details? If you have one (and inevitabily you will need to provide one, because a client might want to see all logs from the past day no matter their severity, for example), in the results you will have to include the level property *in the body* of each `LogMessage` resource, so that your clients can differentiate between the severity of the messages.

So for these reasons, I would prefer solution 2, even though, as I said, there aren't any hard rules for how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me how you are storing the results here, but it appears as if you are storing the `message` and the `logLevel` separately.

If so, I would think about how this will look if you want to export the logs at some point later. How easy will it then be to extract `logLevel`? My initial hunch is that this would be easier if you use your second option.

On the other hand, perhaps one does not need to rule out the other; if applying the URL solution makes life easier, but you don't have any explicit reason to remove `level` from `Body`, then perhaps you could use both?:

```
Method: POST
URI: /{logLevel}/
Body: {
 "level": {either string or enum},
 "message": "..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition REST (Representational State Transfer) Apis should represent the application state. In other words there are some standards when creating the urls, so you can consider the naming practices to maybe influence your decision if you not entirely sure.

Some links to follow:
[Rest Naming practices 1](https://metamug.com/article/rest-api-naming-best-practices.html)

[Rest naming practices 2](https://dilmikottachchi.medium.com/restful-api-endpoint-naming-convention-987be3d23c46)

In short, you have **resources**, **collections**, and **actions**. Urls should  reflect clearly what that endpoint does.

Based on that the second URL is the one to use. The endpoint adds a log message to the logs collection:

```
Method: POST
URI: ..../logs/
Body: {
 "level": {either string or enum},
 "message": "..."
}
```

The level is a specification of the message that the endpoints url should not care about.